# Unable to authenticate using AAD although both apps are on same tenant

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-active-directory

I have one WPF app. Lets name it "demoClient". I have done an app registration on aad for "demoClient". Let's name it "demoClientAppRegistration". When i click the sign in button on "demoClient" i am supposed to be sending a token to "demoServer" for authentication. "demoServer" is also registered on AAD with the name "demoServerAppRegistration". Both of them are in the same tenant "tenantIDandNotDomainName" In the wpf app I have the following code in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

public MainWindow()

```
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            // Read the Azure AD app registration settings from app.config
            _clientId = "demoClientAppRegistrationClientId";
            
            _redirectUri = "http://localhost/demoClientWPFapp";
            _resource = "https://demoServer.azurewebsites.net";
            _authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantIDandNotDomainName";
        }

        private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string accessToken = await GetTokenAsync();
            string apiResponse = await CallApiAsync(accessToken);
            // handle the API response or display it in the UI
        }

        private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            // Configure the PublicClientApplication
            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(_redirectUri)
                .WithAuthority(_authority)
                .Build();

            // Define the authentication scopes
            string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{_resource}/Files.Read" };

            // Acquire an access token
            AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        private async Task<string> CallApiAsync(string accessToken)
        {
        string apiUri = "api://demoClientAppRegistrationID/Files.Read";

            // Call the API with the access token
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUri);

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // ...
        }
```

The following code is the Program.cs file of demoServer dot net core webapp which is published to demoServer.azurewebsites.net:

class Program
{
private static readonly string clientId = "demoClientAppRegistrationId";
private static readonly string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantIDandNotDomainName";
private static readonly string apiUri = "api://demoServerAppRegistrationId";

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new[] { apiUri + "/Files.Read" };
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        Console.WriteLine($"Access token: {result.AccessToken}");

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUri);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine($"Response: {content}");
    }
}
```

I have added the permisions properly. I am still getting the error :
AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://demoServer.azurewebsites.net was not found in the tenant named tenantIDandNotDomainName. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Can anyone guide me where have i gone wrong?

Update:
After following @Sridevi 's method i am facing this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BEiW.png)

Update 2:
I believe the current flow is not what i want. I have done a new flow where i am facing a different error
[Jwt bearer token audience invalid even though correct audience is in token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75936887/jwt-bearer-token-audience-invalid-even-though-correct-audience-is-in-token)

Comment: Are you getting **access token** when you run the code till `Console.WriteLine($"Access token: {result.AccessToken}");` by commenting the remaining part?

Comment: @Sridevi Yes. Also i want the client to pass the access token. I think here the server is fetching the access token and validating it. I think the flow is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I registered one Azure AD application as **demoServerApp** and exposed an API by adding **`Files.Read`** scope like below:

[image]

You can find above **scope** in your client application like this:

[image]

Now, select the **API permission** and click on `Add permissions` like below:

[image]

Make sure to add **admin consent** to the above permission like this:

[image]

When I tried to acquire access token by passing **App service URL** as scope, I got **same error** as below:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
class Program
{
    private static readonly string clientId = "491fc7d8-61cb-4fcd-95ba-xxxxxx";
    private static readonly string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/2f6e32f4-8752-4f56-9154-xxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    private static readonly string apiUri = "https://demoServer.azurewebsites.net";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new[] { apiUri + "/Files.Read" };
        var result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        Console.WriteLine($"Access token: {result.AccessToken}");
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**In Browser:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, make sure to pass **`App ID URI`** of server
> application in `apiUri` variable and change **redirect URI** to your
> App service URL.

When I ran modified code by making above changes, I got **consent screen** like this:

[image]

After consenting the above screen, I authenticated successfully and got the **access token** in the response like below:

[image]

To confirm that, I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) where I got **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims like below:

[image]

In your case, change `_resource` and `_redirectUri` variables in your **MainWindow.xaml.cs** file like this:

```cs
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Read the Azure AD app registration settings from app.config
            _clientId = "demoClientAppRegistrationClientId";
            _redirectUri = "https://demoServer.azurewebsites.net";
            _resource = "api://demoServerAppRegistrationId";
            _authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantIDandNotDomainName";
        
        private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string accessToken = await GetTokenAsync();
            string apiResponse = await CallApiAsync(accessToken);
            // handle the API response or display it in the UI
        }

        private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            // Configure the PublicClientApplication
            IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(_redirectUri)
                .WithAuthority(_authority)
                .Build();

            // Define the authentication scopes
            string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{_resource}/Files.Read" };

            // Acquire an access token
            AuthenticationResult result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Also i think i am not sure about the flow of the code that i have written. I want the client to get an access token from the aad and then pass it to the server for validation and authentication. For the code that I have written is the code flow at par with I am thinking? @Sridevi

Comment: i am getting this error "api scheme is not supported"

Comment: Could you include the error screenshot by editing your question?